# How to sum after removing duplicates

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have one question in mysql.

myTable right below.

```
Location     Name           Stock
A-site       Keyboard       2
A-site       Mouse          1
B-site       Keyboard       2
D-site       Monitor        1
A-site       Keyboard       -1
C-site       Desktop        1
```

I would like to express it like this:

```
Name         A-site   B-site   C-site   D-site    Total
Keyboard     1        2        0        0         3
Mouse        1        0        0        0         1
Monitor      0        0        0        1         1
Desktop      0        0        1        0         1
```

deduplication and summation are needed.

Please help me on how to make the query in mysql.

Thanks.

Later added:
"Location" is a variable. So, in order to use sum by comparison like SUM(IF..),
I need to know the deduplicated list in advance.
The point of this question is this.

Comment: Have you seen  [this "tutorial"](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-sum-with-group-by.php)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display (e.g. the pivot) in application code. And don't include 'wanna' in questions unless actively seeking downvotes.

Comment: @Noah Boegli, Thank for reply.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank for reply. ok, I will try to be careful wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `pivot` problem. It can be solved by next query:

```
select 
    Name,
    sum(if(Location = 'A-site', Stock, 0)) as `A-site`,
    sum(if(Location = 'B-site', Stock, 0)) as `B-site`,
    sum(if(Location = 'C-site', Stock, 0)) as `C-site`,
    sum(if(Location = 'D-site', Stock, 0)) as `D-site`,
    sum(Stock) as total
from stock
group by Name
order by Name
;
```

[SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=ffed33d6ad3e7d28327433f2105ebb09&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Result:

```
+==========+========+========+========+========+=======+
| Name     | A-site | B-site | C-site | D-site | total |
+==========+========+========+========+========+=======+
| Desktop  | 0      | 0      | 1      | 0      | 1     |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| Keyboard | 1      | 2      | 0      | 0      | 3     |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| Monitor  | 0      | 0      | 0      | 1      | 1     |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| Mouse    | 1      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 1     |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, cool. I'm sorry to my mistake missed details. So, to write in SUM(IF...) command line, I need to know the location array that has been deduplicated in advance because "Location" is variable in every day (name change, add & remove...).